# Proving equality for natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

Given an equality such as $15(s^2 + s) = (t^2 + t)$, if we want to solve for $(t,s) \in \mathbb{N^2}$ which satisfies this equation using only peano axioms of $\mathbb{N}$, how would we do that? I notice that if $s = t $ then the left term is gonna be 15 times bigger than the right term. So i tried a bunch of different $s$ and $t$ values and found that the only solution is $s = t = 0$. But how do i show this formally with peano axioms? I find them very difficult to work with since it doesn't use integers, subtraction, rationals and division.

Comment: $s=t=0$ is not the only solution. $15(2^2+2)=90=9^2+9$

Comment: @KeithBackman How do we find the general solution then? Since going over infinite combinations of natural number pairs is not plausible.

Comment: If I had a general solution, I would have posted it. I just wanted to correct your impression that there are no non-trivial solutions. I quickly found the example by considering that $15=3\cdot 5$, and $t^2+t=t(t+1)$ which are two consecutive numbers. So $3,5$ must divide $t \text{ or }t+1$.At that point, I was clearly way outside of Peano axioms, so I just posted the observation as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$15(2s+1)^2= (2t+1)^2+14.$$

This is an example of a standard Pell's equation problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

This equation has infinitely many solutions some of which can be generated as follows:-

Let $X=2s+1, Y=2t+1$, then $$15X^2= Y^2+14.$$

For example, this has the obvious solution $X_1=1,Y_1=1$. From this solution we can generate further solutions from the relations $$X_{n+1}=4X_n+Y_n, Y_{n+1}=15X_n+4Y_n.$$

So $X_2=5,Y_2=19$ and $X_3=39, Y_3=151$ and so on.

Then $(s,t)=(0,0),(2,9),(19,75)$ and so on.

Comment: This type $u^2-Dv^2=k$ of Pell equation with $k \ne 1$ may have no solution, or one *or more* families of solutions, depending on the non-square positive $D.$ I haven't checked whether in this case there are more families of solutions, but would be curious.

Comment: @coffeemath. Yes there are others e.g a family from 3,11. I've clarified the wording on this so as not to give the OP the wrong impression.